# Remote Desktop Server application

Tags: c#, remote-desktop

Hi i want to create a c# based remote desktop application
i found this solution which is written in java ([link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36065/Java-Remote-Desktop-Administration))

so far i created a basic TCP server which supports byte transfer.

Application on windows OS

1. Server listen port:3380
2. Receive connection -> transfer RDP

Application in linux OS

1. Using basic application such as rdesktop to connect
2. Python script to transfer files

Does it exist any library or anything that can help me with this kind of project
or can anybody help me convert the java "RemoteServer.zip" code to c#

Comment: You need to decide if you "want to create..." or simply want an implementation to use/look at. Not clear from the question... And even after fixing that the scope of the question will probably be outside of SO (too broad or asking for Java->C# conversion).

Comment: Have you tried to google `c# rdp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not that hard to build a remote desktop application in .NET. This can be done using `AxMSTSCLib` (*ActiveX component*) to connect to the remote computer. Microsoft has a *“Microsoft RDP client control”* ActiveX control that we be used for this purpose.

1. Add a reference to *“Microsoft Terminal Services Control Type Library”* from the COM tab.
2. Specify the logic to Connect to the Remote Desktop

   ```
   rdp.Server = txtServer.Text;
   rdp.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
   IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
   secured.ClearTextPassword = txtPassword.Text;
   rdp.Connect();
   ```

Found a couple of references:

1. [Remote Desktop using C#.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET)
2. [Create a Remote Desktop Viewer using C# and WCF](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/04/create-a-remote-desktop-viewer-using-c-and-wcf/)